# Is there any way to be able to cast a spell as an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, opportunity-attack, spheres-of-power, path-of-war

Is there any way in Pathfinder to be able to cast a spell (any casting time of a standard action or less) in order to take advantage of AOO's. Now, I know spells already cast like held touch spells (shocking grasp) will grant you that AOO, but that spell has already been cast, and Im interested in being able to cast.

If pathfinder has such an ability that is great, but the game Im playing is also using Path of War and Spheres of Power. My caster is going to be SoP caster.

PoW has the feat [Seize the Opportunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/feats/seize-the-opportunity-combat/) which allows you to use an attack action (such as vital strike) which helps open us possibilities.

SoP can also use [quicken spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/feats/) which reduces the [casting time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#Casting_Time) ([casting time table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#Protection) - scroll up)of its spells. Most spells are standards unless you add metamagic feats (except quicken) and the fastest are swift and then move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are expanded rules for SoP, not located on d20psrd, and in the expanded talents for destruction is one that allows you to make AOO's with your blast. Its called [Energetic Response](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/destruction#toc9).

Answer (score 8):

A [bloodrager](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/) that's wearing a [*ring of vengeful blood magic*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-vengeful-blood-magic/) can 3/day while in a [bloodrage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/#TOC-Bloodrage-Su-) cast a spell as an attack of opportunity. The spell must have a casting time of 1 standard action or less and *either* target *or* include in its area the creature that provoked an attack of opportunity from the bloodrager. The ring has a price of 5,400 gp.

A generous GM *may* allow any creature to use the *ring* if that creature first succeeds on a [Use Magic Device](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) skill check made to emulate the level 1 bloodrager class feature bloodrage (DC 20) to convince the *ring* that the user is in a bloodrage—sort of like how Lidda convinces the magic chalice that she activated it using a turn undead attempt she didn't have, an example in the *Player's Handbook* (2003) description of the skill [Use Magic Device](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#use-magic-device) (86). (This example is absent from the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* *SRD*, therefore it's also absent from *Pathfinder*.) However, this is *far* from a sure thing, and the GM should be consulted about this process *before* the nonbloodrager PC buys a *ring of vengeful blood magic*.

Other than this magic item, I think a player's left asking the GM if *3.5* feats can be adapted to *Pathfinder*. For example, the metapsionic feat [Opportunity Power](http://dndsrd.net/psionicFeats.html#opportunity-power) (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 48-9) could serve as a template for a similar *Pathfinder* metamagic feat, as could the epic feat [Spell Opportunity](http://dndsrd.net/epicFeats.html#spell-opportunity) (*Epic Level Handbook* 67).

---

***Note:*** Casting spells is already *the game's most powerful ability, and that ability is made* even more *powerful if the caster can cast spells A) when it's not the caster's turn, and B) without the caster needing to expend her normal actions. A GM would be wise to strictly limit any adapted or homebrew ability of a caster to cast spells as an attack of opportunity.*

Answer (score 1):

There is also a third party feat option, named [Reflexive Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/legendary-games/ki-feats/reflexive-spell-ki-metamagic/). It's fairly specifically aimed at a monk/caster build, although can also be achieved via an additional (third party) feat. In addittion, this is a metamagic feat that requires a slot two higher, AND preparation of the spell (unless you are a spontaneous caster), and also costs a Ki Point to actually perform. So, it's fairly inefficient and costly, but does fit the bill.